# log4j warning (Please initialize the log4j system properly.) when running java application as jar

Tags: java, logging, jar, log4j

I am now creating a standalone java application which needs to be run as an executable jar.I have configured log4j for proper logging. It writes all the log files when running the application from eclipse.But when I ran the executable jar it comes up with a warning as
** log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger 
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info. **
Can someone please suggest how to solve the issue?

Comment: From past experience, I've found that sometimes other plugins also install a version of log4j, and when there are two instances of it running, they don't play nice. See if that's the case for you.

Comment: You do not have log4j.xml in your classpath

Comment: you can "initialize the log4j system properly".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may not have a valid or correct configuration. Add this to your main method.

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

Failing that , the properties file may not be set up properly if you are using maven in the pom.

The other case is that you have two different logging frameworks in use. Use one or the other.

Another try would be doing something like this to set the property or log4j rootlogger :

```
 Properties prop = new Properties(); 
 prop.setProperty("log4j.rootLogger", "WARN");
 PropertyConfigurator.configure(prop);
```

Also you can try adding a system property to the command line when you start Java:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///path/to/your/log4j.properties
```

Last ditch effort is:

Move Your log4j.properties file into the src folder. Open Windows explorer, browse to the directory where your project resides in. Browse to bin directory and delete all the folders with in it.

Now in eclipse click project-->clean-->OK

This would force it to build the project again,all the contents delete from bin directory will be recreated. Then use the executable jar again when you newly build it.

Comment: I just assume that a little more explanation/information is likely to be appreciated

Comment: A simple check of the documentation of this class would explain exactly what this method does? I'll edit it any way.

Comment: @Stultuske Also, your comment above isn't exactly explained very well either.  
'you can "initialize the log4j system properly". –'

Comment: My comment was just that: a 'comment'. You provid this as an answer, there is a big difference between the two of them. The point behind my comment was: 'the error message tells you exactly what you have to do to solve it, so don't try to figure out what to do, but how to do it'

Comment: @CowboyFarnz I tried adding the configuration in 2 ways. 'PropertyConfigurator.configure(<<absolute path to my log4j.properties>>);'
'BasicConfigurator.configure();' But none of then worked

Comment: @Stultuske at the end of the day this is arbitrary because no matter what, any answer or comment will simply be speculative as we cannot see OP's project/code..

Comment: @CowboyFarnz Sorry I could not find any such flag as additivity in my code. Could you tell me in which it can be found?

Comment: log4j.additivity in your properties file. If it is set to false then the log messages which are coming to your logger will not be propagated to it’s parent loggers. So set to true.

Comment: @MPK I have edited my answeragain, try the last step in the answer and see if that works.

Comment: @CowboyFarnz Thanks for you suggestions. I got that working with adding the system property already. But I am looking for a configuration such that I can avoid the system property in my cmd when running the jar

Comment: @MPK Ok, see my answer again for my last ditch attempt at fixing this.

Comment: @CowboyFarnz Yes it did work with the configuration line added to main class 'PropertyConfigurator.configure("/opt/resources/log4j.properties");' Thanks a lot

Comment: @MPK No problem, can you please accept this as the answer if it helped?

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding the below configuration on my main class.        `PropertyConfigurator.configure("/opt/resources/log4j.properties");`                    and it did work. Eventhough it is still showing the warning message but it is writing the log files.